# Reading Javascript Comments

Tags: javascript, comments

While the point of Javascript comments (in fact, comments in general) is that they are **not** parsed by the compiler, I was wondering if there is a way to actually read comments using Javascript - i.e.

```
/* Hello, world! */
function readComment() {
    alert(readsTheCommentSomehow()) //Would alert "Hello, World!"
}
```

The use case of something like this would be something like [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc), or something cooler like getting code to change what it does dependant of the comment above it. I'm sure that there are other reasons to want to do this, too.

So far, the only way that I have considered doing this is by actually (somehow) making the Javascript read its own code, split by things like `/*`, `\n`, `//`, `*/` and return the comments that way.

Is this really the best way to approach this problem, or am I missing something?

Comment: Only way is to load the file as text and write your own parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments *are* parsed (then discarded) by the compiler. Many tools that provide a parser, like [esprima](http://esprima.org/) and [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), expose the intermediate stages (the abstract syntax tree) which [can be used to extra comments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-extract-comments).

By the time the code is *executed*, comments have been discarded, along with anything else that won't actually impact how the code runs.

There are plenty of JS documentation tools (like [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)) that use comments to provide documentation and simply grab them out of the parse, typically without executing code. Once you have a parser that can produce an AST with comment nodes, you can walk that tree and tie the comments to the following node.

Note that whitespace is often discarded before comments or, if it can be, skipped by the parser entirely (this is more difficult in JS, with ASI).

Answer (score 3):

You can use an AST parser and transformer like babel to read and change your code. Following is simple and naive example on how to read and change tour code according to your comments: http://astexplorer.net/#/5ezZ2lwYHQ

original code:

```
// does something
// and other stuff
function doSomething() {
  console.log('hello');
}
```

babel ast transformer:

```
export default function ({types: t}) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      FunctionDeclaration(path) {
        if (path.node.leadingComments) {
          const text = path.node.leadingComments.map(comment => comment.value).join('\n');
          const change = t.expressionStatement(
            t.callExpression(
              t.memberExpression(t.identifier('console'), t.identifier('log')), 
                [
                  t.stringLiteral(`Function has comments:${text}`)
                ]));

          path.node.body.body.unshift(change);
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```